# Issue about load .obj (ifstream) in android

Tags: c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, vulkan

I'm new to the NDK and android graphics development, and I'm trying to use the code below to load the .obj file.

```
std::ifstream ifs("/storage/emulated/0/VulkanResource/texture/viking_room1.obj");
```

The strange thing is, this code works fine on PC, but not work in android, besides, when I change the .obj to .png, it will work. The .txt doesn't work as well. (I have viking_room1.obj, viking_room1.txt, viking_room1.png in the same dictionary, the .txt and .png files are both changing from .obj by tweaking the suffix )

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

and I have added the code above and change the application's read storage authority. Could anyone help, thanks!

---

update:
This is my code in android, it would output "!ifs", but when I change viking_room1.obj to .png, it will output "ifs". and I have viking_room1.obj, viking_room1.png in the same dictionary

```
std::ifstream ifs("/storage/emulated/0/VulkanResource/texture/viking_room1.obj", std::ios::binary);
    if (!ifs){
        LOGD("!ifs");
    } else {
        LOGD("ifs");
    }
```

Comment: You are opening `std::ifstream` as a text input (which is default, when no arguments passed), therefore I guess your problems come from EOL interpretation differences on different systems. It is usually a good idea opening all streams as binary (`std::ios::binary`) and handling EOLs at application level.

Comment: @gkv311Thanks for replying! Do you mean using code like this? ```std::ifstream ifs("/storage/emulated/0/VulkanResource/texture/viking_room1.obj", std::ios::binary); ```

Comment: still not work : (

Comment: It would be helpful describing in more detail (e.g. in C++ code) what "doesn't work" means in your case, and how files actually appear in the file system.

Comment: sorry for the undistinct description. I update the content above@gkv311